# Laravel - Filter collection with closure on relationship

Tags: laravel

Wondering if there is a way to use closure on a relationship in order to filter the whole line if there isn't a value which corresponds?

Example code:

```
foreach ($paiementMethods as $value) {
            $giftCards = GiftCard::with(['userEntered', 'userEmployee', 'client', 'payement', 'payement.payementMethods' => function($query) use ($value)
            {
                $query->where('id', $value);
            }])
            ->where('date','>=', $dateStart)
            ->where('date','<=', $dateEnd)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

            $giftCardsCollection = $giftCardsCollection->merge($giftCards);
        }
    }
```

In this example, if `$query->where` doesn't find a row for the `payement.payementMethods` which matches the `$value`, I want the `giftCard` to return null. The result I get is the `giftCard` with only the relation on `payement.payementMethods` being `empty`.

My other solution would be to query the giftCard and after that checking the `$value` to see if I have to include the giftCard in the collection or not.

Best regards

Comment: instead of loop .try using wherein   $giftCards = GiftCard::with(['userEntered', 'userEmployee', 'client', 'payement', 'payement.payementMethods' => function($query) use ($paiementMethods)
    {
        $query->whereIn('id', $paiementMethods);
    }])
        ->where('date','>=', $dateStart)
        ->where('date','<=', $dateEnd)
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();

Comment: Tried your answer which is much cleaner but I still get the rows which have a different paiement method type. For example, if I select "Cash" I still get the rows which have "Card" as payement method. @JohnLobo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `whereHas`, it can be solved

```
$giftCards = GiftCard::with(['userEntered', 'userEmployee', 'client', 'payement', 'payement.payementMethods'])
        ->whereHas( 'payement.payementMethods', function($query) use ($paiementMethods) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $paiementMethods);
    })
        ->where('date','>=', $dateStart) 
        ->where('date','<=', $dateEnd) 
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```